# Keep multiple windows focused at once in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, gaming, window-focus

At the risk of this becoming XY, I'll state my purpose. A few games (such as Kingdom Rush) have this annoying habit of automatically pausing when you click in another window (so that the game window loses focus).

I want focus for multiple windows, so I can work with a browser whilst the game still runs in the other window (both are tiled on the same screen).

Is there a program to help here, or maybe there's another workaround?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @MC10: Not necessarily as I don't require input for the game. I just want it to keep running.

Comment: Even you are not giving input, Windows itself can only focus on one window.

Comment: See Vercas's answer in the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

This probably can not be set from Windows. The game will realize that it has lost focus and it will get paused.

You should try to modify the game instead:

1. In some games there are settings for this in the options. ex: "Window auto-pause".
2. You should try to put the game in windowed mode and check if it
   still pauses.
3. Steam games usually have an .ini that you can modify for some
   advanced settings like this one:

`Steamapps/common/xcom-enemy-unknown/engine/config/baseengine.ini`

`bPauseOnLossOfFocus=TRUE`

set to false and it will no longer pause.

You should be looking for `settings.ini` or `options.ini` or anything similar.
You can even make a search inside the game directory for `*.ini`

Comment: Thanks for your input. No such file or setting for Kingdom Rush unfortunately. When in Windowed mode I did however try clicking on the main taskbar icon, and it disappeared though still ran (unfortunately, I don't want it to disappear).

Comment: I did not find any better solutions for this game.